# Does GRANT EXECUTE to a stored procedure give you permission to access all objects inside it?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a procedure which selects data from a table in another database and also uses `sp_send_dbmail`. It seems execute permission is denied on cross database calls inside the procedure.

Can someone confirm that I need separate permissions on these cross database objects too or is there any way to grant execute permission so it can access anything under that proc?

This is the SQL statement for granting execute permission:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::uspAppStoredProcedure TO AppRole;
```

This is the error I got:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail',
>   database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

I got a similar error for trying to select data from another database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the [`cross db ownership chaining` option in SQL Server, which is disabled by default.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188694.aspx)

`uspAppStoredProcedure` is attempting to execute a stored procedure outside of its ownership chain, so it would need explicit permission granted to execute the `sp_send_dbmail`.

It would be possible to enable ownership chaining on the databases involved, which would remove the need for granting specific permissions, but doing so would present a security risk... so it would likely be better to grant explicit access as needed.

[This article goes into additional details on cross database ownership chaining.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/)

Another potential solution would be to make use of the [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) clause when defining the stored procedure, which would allow you to execute under the context of a different user as [described in this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1227/granting-permission-with-the-execute-as-command-in-sql-server/).

This would allow you to create a stored procedure that would allow specific users to execute it while avoiding having to grant permissions to the underlying objects directly to the users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All makes sense now.